# Was Voldemort's body destroyed when he attacked Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

Before the opening of the Sorcerer's Stone, when Voldemort attacked Harry and failed, was his body destroyed or only killed?

Answer (score -1):

Voldemort's body was destroyed and Voldemort didn't die but changed forms.

Comment: Some citations would improve this answer considerably.